# Solving Integration Problem

Tags: integration

What is the value for the following integration :
$\int_{-\infty}^1 (e^{-2|x-2|} dx)$ + $\int_1^\infty (0.5e^{-|x|} dx)$ ? The absolute value is confusing me .

Comment: The first integral would now converge because of the limits going from $-\infty$ to $1$. I've explained my comment in the my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x$ ranges from $−\infty$ to $1$, we have $|x−2|=2−x$ and, when $x$ ranges from $1$ to $\infty$, we have $|x|=x$.

Now,

$$\int_{-\infty}^1 e^{-2|x-2|} = \int_{-\infty}^1 e^{-2(2-x)} = \int_{-\infty}^1 e^{2x - 4} = \frac{1}{e^4}\int_{-\infty}^1 e^{2x} = \frac{1}{2e^4}e^{2x}]_{-\infty}^1 = \frac{1}{2e^2}$$

Similarly,

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^\infty e^{-|x|} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-x} = \frac{1}{2e}$$

Comment: Thank you  very much !